# Passing pointer/reference to object

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I'm writting a simple game where I've `Player` object and `Enemy` object. I want `Enemy` to pursue `Player` but I've no idea what is the right way of passing current `Player`'s position to `Enemy`.

Natively I'm a C++ dev so I was naturally thinking of passing `Player` (probably as an interface) to `Enemy` but I cannot find any clue about such approach in QML.

How should I do it then?

Comment: You should add a bit of some code or snippets, to illustrate what kind of structure you have. But generally, in QML the ideal way is to simply bind properties: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html so here Enemy could have target coordinates, which you bind to player's coordinates, and Enemy doesn't even need to know what a player is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the best way would be using property bindings like `hyde` has already pointed out.

```
// Enemy.qml
Item {

   property int targetX
   property int targetY

// more code

}


// Player.qml
Item {

   property int currentPosX
   property int currentPosY

}

// Main.qml

Enemy {
   id: enemy

   targetX: player.currentPosX
   targetY: player.currentPosY

}

Player {
   id: player

   // Some calculation for the current x and y position   
}
```

Another approach would be to pass the `Player` component to the `Enemy` component. But than you have a little bit coupling. This is maybe the C++ thinking you have pointed out.

```
// Enemy.qml
Item {
   id: enemy    

   property Item myPlayer

   Component.onCompleted: {
      console.log(enemy.myPlayer.currentPosX + 
         " | " + 
         enemy.myPlayer.currentPosY) 
   }

}


// Player.qml
Item {

   property int currentPosX
   property int currentPosY

}

// Main.qml

Enemy {
   id: enemy

   myPlayer: player
}

Player {
   id: player

   // Some calculation for the current x and y position   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ad mentioned [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-index.html):

> JavaScript expressions allow QML code to contain application logic.

Moreover:

> QML offers a highly readable, declarative, JSON-like syntax with support for imperative JavaScript expressions combined with dynamic property bindings.

Because of that, you have not the notion of pointer in the QML environment, unless you push your logic under the hood, writing it in C++.

Anyway, almost everything in JavaScript is passed by reference (that's an acceptable simplification valid for your case, there are also some exceptions like primitive values and immutable objects).

Because of that, you can simply let your instance of `A` refers to an instance of `B`, either by passing it in the *constructor* or setting it by means of a *setter* or whatever (there is a plenty of alternative solutions indeed).

Keep in mind that there is no explicit support for *interfaces* neither in JavaScript nor in QML, so you cannot rely on them, even if you can simulate them (it isn't worth it from my point if view).

How to solve your specific problem?
Well, it depends on your actual code and software architecture, so I cannot say that, I'm sorry. I hope one of the hints above is of any help for you.

Comment: thank you for answer it clarifies a lot. I just look at the QML through the prism of C++ and I try to apply the same solutions. What I need is to understand how such things are done in QML.

Comment: If you find that the response does not fully reply to your question, let me know how I can improve it. I'd be glad to do that.